# jQuery two different delegates

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegates

I have two delegate functions working..but I want that if the img is clicked avoid the click on the `<li>.`

```
<li><img src='img.png'/></li>

$('#listview').delegate('li img', 'click', function(){
    alert('img clicked!');
}); 
$('#listview').delegate('li', 'click', function() { 
    window.open("details.php?id" + $(this).attr('id'), '_blank');
});
```

If the image (inside the li) is clicked I would like NOT to open that page details. Currently, when I click the image it alerts plus show the new page..how  can I avoid that?

Comment: 'delegate' is superseded by 'on' in versions of jQuery above 1.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [event.stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/):

```
$('#listview').delegate('li img', 'click', function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    alert('img clicked!');
});
```

to prevent event buble up the DOM tree.

Comment: why not just stopping propagation with stopPropagation() method? In case of OP i'm quite sure both will work the same but maybe i'm missing something here, so any reason?

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes, based on current OP's question, both methods are correct.